# Gallery images lazy loading?

Tags: jquery, html, gallery

I have this gallery page in a website that has been categorized into sections. The problem is that it loads the entire images on first load, which in turn makes the website very laggy and non responsive.

From what I understand lazy loading would help me here but apparently it's not working with the current code. If you have any other ideas please let me know, or even a way to fix the lazy loading issue.

Sorry this is the current gallery page of the website.
http://www.hishamomran.com/zahabia3/gallery.html

Much appreciated!

Comment: It seems like you want to load more images when the user has scrolled a certain distance down the page

Answer (score 0):

Lazy load is not working because the plugin URL is wrong, see on console, it throws 404 error.
http://www.hishamomran.com/zahabia3/js/jquery.lazyload.js

EDIT: `<img data-original=“img/example.jpg” src=“img/grey.gif”>` this is how you images should be look like. Sure it loads your images if you're putting it to the src attribute.

Comment: Sorry about that, server was still uploading! It's there now and it's still not working!

Comment: I think the script loads and all but it's still loading all the pictures, and it's taking too much time to load!

Comment: Also the gallery starts loading all the images first then focuses on the 'overview' category. Any way to make it load each category on demand?

Comment: There should be a way to apply the lazy loading to the full container. Which is what is there now in the code. I can't add the data-original to over 450 images. Any ideas?

Comment: Why not? just automatically replace the img code with a text editor.